# VB.net - SQLite query response turning empty after first interaction

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

so I'm using SQLite in a VB.net project with a populated database. I'm using the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core and System.Data.SQLite NuGet package libraries. So the problem presents when I'm trying to get the result of a query. At first the SQLiteDataReader gets the response and all the elements of the desired table. I know this cause in the debugger I have a breakpoint after the setting the object and when I check the parameters of the SQLiteDataReader object the Result View shows all the elements of my table, but as soon as I remove the mouse from the object and check it again the Result View turns out empty, without even resuming with the next line of code. Does anyone know if its a known bug or something cause Ive used this exact method of querying a table in another project and it works.

The code:

```
Public Function RunQuery(com As String)
   If CheckConnection() Then
      command.CommandText = com
      Dim response As SQLiteDataReader
      response = command.ExecuteReader
      Dim len As Integer = response.StepCount
      Dim col As Integer = response.FieldCount
      Dim resp(len, col) As Object

      For i = 0 To col - 1
         Using response
             response.Read()
             For j = 0 To len - 1
                 resp(i, j) = response.GetValue(j)
             Next
         End Using
      Next
```

[Debugger with populated result view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avg0z.png)
[Debugger with empty result view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRvw6.png)

edit: added the for loop to show that its not only on the debugger that the result view is empty. When using response.Read() it throws an exception "System.InvalidOperationException: 'No current row'"

Comment: Not sure, but a DataReader is a ForwardOnly data retrieval object. Once you force the debugger to show all records is it possible that your reader is at the end of the records retrieved and thus is unable to show anything else. Did you experience this only in debug? What happen if you let it run till the end of the method and then recall again the same method?

Comment: @Steve, so after letting the code run the .StepCount and .FieldCount return the correct the correct amount of columns and rows of the table but if I use a method like .Read() that returns one of the rows of the elements of the result view it returns this exception "System.InvalidOperationException: 'No current row'". So the result view is indeed emptying for some reason.

Comment: @Steve, if I let it run without any breakpoints it shows this exception "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: You have too many loops and the one really needed is missing. First you should loop with _while(response.Read)_ to extract record by record, then inside this loop you could start another loop with a normal for to look at each column of the current record extracted by Read

Comment: @Steve, Found the solution! So I did what you suggested of implementing a while instead of the initial for loop but it continued with the same error. Comparing my work with a previous one i noticed that I had used the "using" method before starting with the loops, which surprisingly resolved the error I was having. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have told you in the comment, a DataReader derived class is a forward only retrieval object. This means that when you reach the end of the records returned by the query, that object is not capable to restart from the beginning.

So if you force the debugger to *enumerate the view* the reader reaches the end of the results and a second attempt to show the content of the reader fails.

The other part of your problem is caused by a misunderstanding on how to work on the reader. You should loop over the Read result not using a StepCount property. This property as far as I know, is not standard and other data providers don't support it. Probably it is present in the SQLite Provider because for them it is relatively easy to count the number of records while other providers don't attempt do calculate that value for performance reasons.

However, there are other ways to read from the reader. One of them is to fill a DataTable object with its Load method that conveniently take a DataReader

```
 Dim data As DataTable = New DataTable()
 Using response
     data.Load(response)
 End Using
' Now you have a datatable filled with your data. 
' No need to have a dedicated bidimensional array
```

A DataTable is like an array where you have Rows and Columns instead of indexes to iterate over.

Comment: Thank you. Didnt knew there was this option and its indeed better than declaring an array if you can only run by the DataReader once.